# Eva / Ava AI movies coincidence?

Tags: science-fiction, ex-machina, the-machine, eva

If you've seen [*Ex Machina*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0470752/), [*The Machine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2317225/) and [*Eva*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1298554/) you've probably noticed the odd coincidence of three movies in the last few years about artificial intelligence all with protagonists named Eva or Ava (always pronounced AY-vah). But was it a coincidence? Are these movies connected somehow out-of-universe, maybe through common writers or source material?

Comment: Probably the Bible.

Comment: Yep, the story of Eve in the technological era. There's also EVE from  *Wall-E* (which Wall-E pronounces as 'Eva').

Comment: In the overwhelming majority of languages the biblical name ends on -a (as the original does), it didn't even occur to me that it is different in English. Maybe it is more obvious then. The name directly translates to "the animated".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The common source material is the Christian Bible, specifically the story of [Adam and Eve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_and_Eve). Eve is created from source material from the first human, Adam, and then animated. Her name translates to "the animated". In most languages as in the original (hawa) it ends on -a. The stories all are strongly related to the biblical story, they are "the story of Eve in the technological era" (@Walt). As all the movies mentioned were produced in a country with primarily Christian mythological background this is used as the common background and reference.

Comment: Also note the name of the humans in Ex Machina, Caleb and Nathan, which are both biblical names and further supports the link to the Christian bible.

Answer (score -2):

In response, I'd like to first share some relevant references and comment on them. The original animated movie Ghost in the Shell, based on Japanese manga by Shirow Masamune, came out almost 20 years ago, before the anti-climactic journey of civilization into the technological era, across the threshold of the prophesied Y2K doomsday, which was representative of the thematic genre of science fiction characterized as the war between man and machine that the Terminator and Matrix series were trademarks of. All 3 works strongly allude to Biblical concepts. The theme of artificial humanity is expressed more readily in iRobot, based on work by Isaac Asimov, but it references the Bible only as part of a comedic one-liner. In the proximity of 2011, a coincidence occurred where many works dealing with The Maya and a 2012 doomsday were published under simultaneously conceived and conducted projects while at the same time, in the same manner, as works dealing with a Christian Conspiracy linked to Leonardo DaVinci, Nostradamus, and the Knights Templar. Circling back, an animated movie Appleseed, was released as a precedent of sorts by breaking from the manga tradition and coming out of "the west" instead of "the east" - hence not a "japanimation" film. Appleseed was inclusive of strongly Biblical themes and full of references to Greek Mythology as well as telling a story about AI and humanity in a post-apocalyptic setting. Completing the circle: the title of Ghost in the Shell came from Concept of Mind by Gilbert Ryle published in the 1950s as a rebuttal to Rene Descartes' Meditations of First Philosophy from the 16th century in which he famously postulated "I think therefore I am" - on an interesting side note it was Ryle who coined the term embraced by Dualists and used afterwards to refer to the theories of Descartes regarding the existence of  a soul. Descartes had made a scientific case for the existence of the Christian God in his work and Ryle tried the case as if in a court of law where the usage of modern knowledge was to condescendingly rebuke the superstitious ignorance of simple folk of former days and to displace it from society like a stigma as was done by the Supreme Court when it banned the Bible from public school. So you see, the Christian perspective in the technological age is neither new nor self-contained, and in many ways, you could say it is the product of an intermingling of stories and themes that have developed over the years, some old, some recent, and the reason for the coincidence of recurring elements is the popularity and resonance they have - in short, they are highly marketable.

Comment: Also, I'd like to note that spoken names and, of course words, which are spelled in English using the roman alphabet are usually phonetically transposed (forgive me if I did not use correct terms). This means that the way they are written is meant to recreate the way they sound. Many words of "European" origin mean something, but many words don't have a connection to a written root corresponding with a spoken dialect or don't retain a concise record of progression from former to current form. This is because the roman alphabet has letters that previous languages did not.

Comment: That's why I am going to need some basis for the claim that the overwhelming majority of languages refer to Eve as Eva or end with an a. In what language was the Bible written originally? What is the actual root of the name? Remember that the story of Adam and Eve is from the Old Testament, written well before the roman alphabet existed, before Christianity, and it was translated into English from first Latin and then Greek and then revised using languages written in both the Hebrew alphabet which has no vowels and Aramaic alphabet. Also the OT says Eve means "mother of all the living".

Comment: dude what are you talking about? This is a really long answer plus 2 giant comments that barely touches the question. Make it concise and just add as much context as relevant to the question.